# Spyder3 - AttributeError: 'SpyderKernel' object has no attribute '_show_mpl_backend_errors'

Tags: python, ipython

I have a problem with Spyder3. When I open it, this warning appears on the console.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-db6556ffc451>", line 1, in <module>
    get_ipython().kernel._show_mpl_backend_errors()

AttributeError: 'SpyderKernel' object has no attribute '_show_mpl_backend_errors'
```

Can someone help me? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and this warning appeared after I ran the command below on the terminal. I was trying to install the new version of Spyder.

```
pip install -U spyder
```

Thanks in advace for the help!

Comment: A bit late in the same but, I have had the same issue lately, starting Spyder from command line didnt fix it for me - as it turns out the issue comes Tornado that hasn't been been updated - if you run pip install spyder-kernels it should tell you that the requirements are already satisfied however it will check that packages are up-to-date and update Tornado automatically.That fixed it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same happened to me, with the exact same Ubuntu, Python and IPython versions. It seems launching Spyder from the GUI was the problem, I launched it from the terminal and everything worked just fine with the updated Spyder version.

Answer (score -1):

1. uninstall anaconda and delete all its files
2. restart
3. carefully read all instructions while new installation

note: if you are using ubuntu then first make environment then install spyder using pip. (in my case it was solved)